# Issue calling perl script from java

Tags: java, perl

I need to call a perl script at a central location using java with arguements..I have used the following code and it does nothing..Can someone tell me whats missing

```
            final List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();                

            commands.add("perl");
            commands.add("I:/golden_scripts/make-tp-patch.pl");
            commands.add(destpath+"/"+"scrfile.txt.org");
            commands.add(pro_name);
            commands.add(patch);
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
            Process p1 = pb.start();
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing all about your environment.

Comment: Is the quote in `new ProcessBuilder("commands)` a typo?

Comment: I am running it in eclipse EE inside a web applcation built using struts2 and java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4048489/312407

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your command is correct (and not the typo with the extra " in your post) and your environment is set up correctly, you probably want to block until the perl script completes.

```
Process p1 = pb.start();
```

Just starts the program. you aren't waiting for it to complete.  you probably want to call `p1.waitFor()` which will wait for the program to finish and return an exit code.

then when waitFor() returns you know the program is done or has errored out.  It is probably also a good idea to use the inputStreams from getInputStream() and getErrorStream() to get the STDOUT and STDERR messages the perl script prints as it runs.

Comment: Failing to consume all the bytes from the Input and Error stream may cause the external program to lock up mid-execution.  I'd say consuming those streams is a mandatory part of "execing" the external process correctly.  I usually launch background threads to consume the streams and have the ProcessBuilder thread use waitFor right after launching the background threads.